# Dimension of motions of an atom vs a molecule wrt energy/heat calculation

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, degrees-of-freedom

I had just started a course on [Climate change](https://www.coursera.org/learn/global-warming/lecture/vgWks/heat) and it helped me refresh the notion of heat.

Heat as given by the equation,

$E = \frac 1 2 kT$

is the amount of energy of a particle at a given temperature T, measured in Kelvin scale.

So for a single atom, like Hydrogen, it'll be,

$E_h = \frac 3 2 kT$, one for each direction of motion.

While I'm not sure why exactly that is the case, I guess that's because of the scalar nature of energy and "total" energy has to be summed up.

However, for a molecule like oxygen, the prof claims that the motion is:

1. 1 Vibrational mode b/w the two atoms
2. 2 rotational mode

I don't get why this will be the case. I assumed it will be 5 axes with:
6 free dimensions of motion -1 due to a constraint.

Looking for help to grasp this notion. Let me know if this question needs to be rephrased or is not correct for the forum.

Comment: Just a quick comment about terminology. *[Heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat)* a form of energy transfer from one place to another, e.g.  heat flowed from the stove into the pot of water. Once the energy has arrived at its destination it is no longer heat. Your first equation gives the *[internal energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy)* of a degree of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

The rotation about the axis of the $O_2$ molecule is negligible compared to the other two (intuitively, minuscule moment of inertia). As for vibration, the molecule is linear, so there is only one bond length which can oscillate.